# How to add info window for clustering marker in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, markerclusterer

I would like to show an info window with an image for all markers in Android. I referred to this [Google Map Cluster Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering?hl=it).

Comment: i have no idea to add custom info window using the cluster library u have any idea

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`MyItem` Class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem;

public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {

    private LatLng mPosition;
    private String mLatitude = "";
    private String mStoreLogo = "";
    private String mLongitude = "";

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public void setPosition(LatLng mPosition) {
        this.mPosition = mPosition;
    }

    public LatLng getmPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public void setmPosition(LatLng mPosition) {
        this.mPosition = mPosition;
    }

    public String getmLatitude() {
        return mLatitude;
    }

    public void setmLatitude(String mLatitude) {
        this.mLatitude = mLatitude;
    }

    public String getmLongitude() {
        return mLongitude;
    }

    public void setmLongitude(String mLongitude) {
        this.mLongitude = mLongitude;
    }

    public String getmStoreLogo() {
        return mStoreLogo;
    }

    public void setmStoreLogo(String mStoreLogo) {
        this.mStoreLogo = mStoreLogo;
    }

}
```

`Map` Activity Class:

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements
        ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>,
        ClusterManager.OnClusterInfoWindowClickListener<MyItem>,
        ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>,
        ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<MyItem> {


    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    private Cluster<MyItem> clickedCluster;
    private MyItem clickedClusterItem;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

        try {
          // Initializing Map from XML :
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Map.this);
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mMapView);

            mMapView = mapFrag.getMap();
            mMapView.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMapView.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMapFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Utils.displayToast("Your device doesn't support Google Map", Map.this);
        }

   // Creating cluster manager object.

    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(Map.this, mMapView);
        mMapView.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(Map.this, mMapView,
                mClusterManager));

        mMapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
        mMapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
        mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(
                new MyCustomAdapterForClusters());
        mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(
                new MyCustomAdapterForItems());
        mMapView.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        mClusterManager
                .setOnClusterClickListener(new OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
                        clickedCluster = cluster;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        mClusterManager
                .setOnClusterItemClickListener(new OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
                        clickedClusterItem = item;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        // Adding Objects to the Cluster.    

        mClusterManager.addItem(mItemData);
                        mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, 7));
        mClusterManager.cluster();
    }

    class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

        public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
            super(context, map, clusterManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item,
                MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
            super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
        }

    }

    // Custom adapter info view :
    public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements InfoWindowAdapter {

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyCustomAdapterForItems() {
            myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.map_info_window_dialog, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtHeader));
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtAddress));

            tvTitle.setTypeface(mTyFaceKreonBold);
            tvSnippet.setTypeface(mTyFaceKreonBold);
            if (clickedClusterItem != null) {
                tvTitle.setText(clickedClusterItem.getmStoreName());
                tvSnippet.setText(clickedClusterItem.getmAddressOne());
            }
            return myContentsView;
        }
    }

     // class for Main Clusters.    
    public class MyCustomAdapterForClusters implements InfoWindowAdapter {

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyCustomAdapterForClusters() {
            myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.map_info_window_dialog, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtHeader));
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtAddress));
            tvSnippet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvTitle.setTypeface(mTyFaceKreonBold);
            tvSnippet.setTypeface(mTyFaceKreonBold);

            if (clickedCluster != null) {
                tvTitle.setText(String
                        .valueOf(clickedCluster.getItems().size())
                        + " more offers available");
            }
            return myContentsView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(MyItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Map.this,NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("mLatitude", item.getmLatitude());
        intent.putExtra("mLongitude", item.getmLongitude());

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClusterInfoWindowClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code is self explanatory. Please add the cluster library and google play services lib to your build path. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: @Deva Kindly show me How are you adding items to the cluster?

Comment: private void readItems() throws JSONException {
       // InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search);
     //  List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
     
     
     Log.e("items size", ""+items.size());
   
         Log.e("items", ""+items);
         mClusterManager.addItems(items);
         
         
         map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLngZoom(items.get(0).getPosition(), 7));
         
         mClusterManager.cluster();
     }

Comment: adding list of latlng in a list and then parse the list to this method..after that added your coding..

Comment: @Deva thats it. It will work. Do you get any exceptions? Any error message?

Comment: Did you call the window adapter like this?  `mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(
                new MyCustomAdapterForItems());`  and         `mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this); 
` Can i see your complete code. Please update that in your question.

Comment: You want to show cluster info dialog or cluster item info dialog? It's working very fine to me. Please show me your code.

Comment: how to remove the plus symbol in cluster show exact count and when click the cluster show all data in info window.....

Comment: @Deva I didn't dig that much, will do if time allows. If you are suppose to do that. Please let me know. Let me learn from you.

Comment: setOnMarkerClickListener - was what I need.